# How can I check if a URL has a valid public TLD?

Tags: php, url, tld

So I'm going to get a URL from a form and I want to make sure that only ones that have a valid public `tld` in them are accepted (so that `http://google.com` is accepted, but not `http://google.notatld`). How would I do this?

Comment: Of interest: http://php.net/parse_url

Answer (score 2):

You can use **tldextract** Library. Check the link [here](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2012/08/28/tldextract/).